# Can't find jupyter notebook's installed location or remove it from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, uninstall, jupyter-notebook

I installed the jupyter notebook ,can't remember how , but when it came to remove it I just can't , it's there and works by simply typing:
"$jupyter notebook " but still :

1. Synaptic does not recognise it's installation.
2. sudo apt list --installed also does not.
3. sudo pip2 uninstall jupyter 
   worked something but still after that jupyter notebook opens.

I can not find any directory by name jupyter when I search in Nautilus except for one in which there is a cookie file.

So I just do not know how to remove it and where it exists.

[image: Uninstalled Jupyter but still it works]

Comment: what's the output of `which -a jupyter`?  There is a similar [question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter)

Comment: @v25 this one :- /home/gaurav/.local/bin/jupyter
/home/gaurav/.local/bin/jupyter
/home/gaurav/.local/bin/jupyter
/home/gaurav/.local/bin/jupyter

Comment: @v25 Also about the similar link you told I tried it already did not works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51772592/2052575).

I'm not sure if it will be the same in you case, but `cat /home/gaurav/.local/bin/jupyter` should show some python code, which among other things has:

```
import jupyter_core
```

So you could try `pip2 uninstall jupyter_core` and see if this has any effect.

You could also delete the file which `which` found: `rm /home/gaurav/.local/bin/jupyter`.

At this point you shouldn't be able to execute `jupyter` from the command line.

If you still suspect that something may be hiding somewhere, then investigate how to [find and check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) your site-packages directory, and possibly investiate installing stuff in virtual environments in the future to prevent this stuff existing system-wide.

Comment: I did this and it worked perhaps :-

Answer (score 0):

This worked perhaps :- `gaurav@gaurav-X555LAB:~$ sudo pip uninstall jupyter_core
The logs are here:- https://paste.gnome.org/pqdm2pd7g
It removed a lot of packages just do not know everything wiped out or not.
So I hope it's removed now , tell me if something went wrong here and if more needs to be done.